# CSS compilation/compression and Source Maps v3

Tags: css, node.js, minify, source-maps

Does anyone know of a tool that will compress/minify/combine my CSS files and produce valid v3 SourceMap that can be used with Chrome? Preferably a NodeJS tool.

The compressors I know of for Node are clean-css, csso, css-condense (uses css-parse but chokes on bootstrap.css) and cssmin (port from YUI but has no CLI). None of these appear to have source-map support.

I think SASS (Ruby) and possibly Less.js are working on implementations, but those are preprocessor tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mincer-sourcemap](https://github.com/mklabs/mincer-sourcemap) seems to be able to generate CSS sourcemaps.

Answer (score 1):

[mincer](https://github.com/nodeca/mincer) assets pipeline 1.0.0+ release comes with source maps support. That's ruby's sprockets port to node.js. Latest state of engines is on [wiki](https://github.com/nodeca/mincer/wiki).

For CSS right now you can use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) + [AutoPrefixer](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer) + [CssWring](https://github.com/hail2u/node-csswring) chain. [SASS](https://github.com/andrew/node-sass) also has sourcemaps support, but it's not yet adopted to mincer.

In nearest future [Stylus](https://github.com/learnboost/stylus) should add source maps support too.

Answer (score 0):

I use https://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/ which works great, also on bootstrap.

It can minify JS and CSS. Handles sourcemaps and bundling of files.

Lots of options, but I use a few xml files to define what should be minified and what should be bundled. You can also just use the command line for it.

My usecase was compile time creation. If yours is runtime creation then you should go with something else.

Comment: "Minify both JS and CSS files, and now optionally produce Source Maps for JavaScript files."
I don't think it produces CSS Source Maps, but correct me if I'm wrong..

Comment: It does if you ask for it. In my .xml file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <output path="corev15.min.css">
    <symbolMap name="v3" path="corev15.min.css.map" />
    <input path="corev15.css" />
  </output>

...